# cost of cutting a plank

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

I know that this question has been asked but i cant understand the problem in my code. I know that we have to use cost in desending order for minimum cost and i did same but still gives wrong output.

A board composed of m×n wooden squares and asks him to find the minimum cost of breaking the board back down into individual 1×1 pieces. To break the board down, Bob must make cuts along its horizontal and vertical lines.

To reduce the board to squares, xn−1 vertical cuts must be made at locations x1,x2,…,xn−2,xn−1 and ym−1 horizontal cuts must be made at locations y1,y2,…,ym−2,ym−1. Each cut along some xi (or yj) has a cost, cxi (or cyj). If a cut of cost c passes through n already-cut segments, the total cost of the cut is n×c.

The cost of cutting the whole board down into 1×1 squares is the sum of the cost of each successive cut. Recall that the cost of a cut is multiplied by the number of already-cut segments it crosses through, so each cut is increasingly expensive.

Input Format

The first line contains a single integer, T, denoting the number of test cases. The subsequent 3T lines describe each test case in 3 lines.

For each test case, the first line has two positive space-separated integers, m and n, detailing the respective height (y) and width (x) of the board. 
The second line has m−1 space-separated integers listing the cost, cyj, of cutting a segment of the board at each respective location from y1,y2,…,ym−2,ym−1. 
The third line has n−1 space-separated integers listing the cost, cxi, of cutting a segment of the board at each respective location from x1,x2,…,xn−2,xn−1.

Note: If we were to superimpose the m×n board on a 2D graph, x0, xn, y0, and yn would all be edges of the board and thus not valid cut lines.

Constraints 
1≤T≤20 
2≤m,n≤1000000 
,0≤cxi,cyj≤1000000000

Output Format

For each of the T test cases, find the minimum cost (MinimumCost) of cutting the board into 1×1 squares and print the value of MinimumCost % (1000000000+7).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t,ch=0;
    long int pos,m,n,h=1,l=1;
    long long int cost=0,*x,*y,temp;
    cin>>t;
    while(t>0)
    {cin>>m>>n;
     cost=0;
    x = new long long int[n-1];
    y = new long long int[m-1];
    for (long i=0;i<m-1;i++)
        cin>>y[i];
    for(long i=0;i<n-1;i++)
        cin>>x[i];
    h=1;
    l=1;
    while((h!=m)|(l!=n))
    {ch=0;
    temp=0;
    for (long i=0;i<m-1;i++)
        if (temp<y[i])
            {temp=y[i];
            pos=i;
            }
    for(long i=0;i<n-1;i++)
        if (temp<x[i])
        {temp=x[i];
        pos=i;
        ch=1;
        }
    cost=cost+temp*(ch==0?l:h);
    if (ch==0)
            {y[pos]=-1;
            h++;}
        else
            {x[pos]=-1;
            l++;
            }

    }
    cout<<cost%1000000007;
    t--;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Test case that gives wrong output:

Input:

5

52 30

2 30 79 47 4 56 47 67 25 30 75 58 47 54 66 61 6 64 28 41 75 36 1 92 42 61 35 56 12 86 84 14 68 63 13 72 19 60 39 96 43 14 55 42 21 73 3 27 37 84 68

64 72 21 56 14 35 44 71 47 82 7 14 50 71 79 23 42 92 14 39 35 81 46 29 2 19 84 81 57

23 43

1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23

60 76

7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7

30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30

58 40

71 58 61 51 33 3 43 48 94 30 29 40 59 83 12 43 64 69 64 65 42 57 40 72 64 98 98 47 56 6 85 79 65 46 30 98 49 25 98 96 7 27 88 66 10 0 62 26 69 78 92 64 87 84 88 51 35

87 50 91 45 35 22 62 81 53 61 83 30 59 31 38 39 19 56 1 20 70 28 41 48 72 57 35 56 46 39 91 85 41 34 30 77 57 93 10

47 94

6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6

17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17

Output

51028

1912

33638

91124

27525

Comment: When you used the debugger, which statement is causing the issue?  What are the values of the variables in the statement?  (Add answers to your post.)

Comment: I recommend using spaces around operators.  It doesn't affect your program's execution, but it does make your program more readable.

Comment: I don't know the values of variable. It's checked for some input online. I will make sure to use spaces next time. Actually on my compiler it seemed clean so never thought of adding spaces.

Comment: Many debuggers have a feature where you can put variables in a window and *watch* their values as you single step through each statement.  Assisting you would be easier if you could single step through your program and let us know which statement is causing the issue.

Comment: You should make a habit of using `delete` or `delete[]` for each `new` or `new[]`.  Otherwise you have a *memory leak*.

Comment: i have included one of the input and output available from that site.

Comment: i have never used a debugger before. since you have mentioned it i will try to use it. but pls try it on your side. yes i forgot about using delete() , i will try to remember that. @ThomasMatthews

Answer (score 0):

This line could be a contributing factor:

```
while((h!=m)|(l!=n))
```

The `|` operator is a *binary arithmetic* operator.

Maybe you were looking for `||`, which is the *logical OR* operator:

```
while((h!=m) || (l!=n))
```

Comment: For discrete input variables, like here, this shouldn't actually make any difference.